# How to specify another timeout queue for NSB?

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NSB 4.4.2
I want to have something like heartbeats on my saga to show processing statistics. 
When i request a timeout it sends to sagas input queue.
In case of many messages prior to this timeout message, IHandleTimeouts may not be fired at specific time.
Is it a bug? Or how can i use separate queue for timeout messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - when a timeout is ready to be dispatched, it is sent to the incoming queue of the endpoint, and if there are already many other messages in there, it will have to wait its turn to be processed.

Another thing you might want to consider, is that the endpoint may be down at that time.

If you want to guarantee that your saga code will be invoked at (or very close to) the time of the timeout, you'll need to set up a high availability deployment first. Then, you should look at setting the SLA required of that endpoint - how quickly messages should be processed, and then monitor the time to breach SLA performance counter.

See here for more information: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/monitoring-nservicebus-endpoints

You should be prepared to scale out your endpoint as needed to guarantee enough processing power to keep up with the load coming in.

NOTE: The reason we use the same incoming queue for processing these timeouts is by design. A timeout message is almost always the same priority or lower than the other business messages being processed by a saga. As such, it doesn't make sense to have them cut ahead of other messages in line.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts are sent to the [endpointname].timeouts

Comment: Sending message XXX.HeartbeatTimeout with ID 50c5cbde-401e-4a44-b9f0-a35d000014aa to destination YYY@ZZZ.

Comment: Where YYY@ZZZ - sagas queue name

Comment: MAybe you can provide a bit more details? what is HartbeatTimeOut is that your own custom setting? are you referring to the serviceControl heartbeat messages?

Comment: This is hy heartbeat timeout class  
public class HeartbeatTimeout  
{  
}  
  
  
this is the way i request timeout:  
RequestTimeout<HeartbeatTimeout>(DateTime.Now + HeartbeatInterval);  
  
And this is the handler:  
  
MySaga : ....., IHandleTimeouts<HeartbeatTimeout>  
  
public void Timeout(HeartbeatTimeout timeout)  
{  
   ...  
  
  // Request next  
  RequestTimeout<HeartbeatTimeout>(DateTime.Now + HeartbeatInterval);  
}

Comment: Really hard to read this, can you share the code on Github or dropbox?